# ‘I weirdly affected my friend’

Tags: sentence-meaning, ambiguity

Can ‘I weirdly affected my friend’ not only mean ‘I affected my friend in a weird way,’ but also ‘I made a weird effect on my friend’?

Comment: *Personally*, I think this is an unusual context where there's ambiguity as to whether the "adverb of manner" attaches more strongly to the ***subject + verb*** *(I affected; **how the act was performed**)* or to the ***object*** *(my friend; **how he was affected / what he was like after being thus affected**).*

Comment: This is a vague sentence. I'm sorry you have to deal with it, but I sure hope you didn't write it yourself. Vagueness is something English tries to avoid.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thank you, I noted it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Weirdly" is an *adverb of manner*. Adverbs affect *verbs*, so in your example it could only really be understood one way as there is only one verb - "affected". So, it means that the *manner* in which you affected your friend was 'weird' - whatever that means. I have to add, it doesn't make a lot of sense.

If you mean to say that the resulting *effect* you had on your friend was weird, you need to remember that 'effect' is a noun, so you can't use an adverb like 'weirdly' on it. You'd need to say "*I had a weird effect on my friend*".

As your verb has an object ("my friend") you don't have a choice of placement for the adverb. For example, you can say "I quickly swam" or "I swam quickly", but if you give the verb an object you can only say "I quickly swam the pool", and not "I swam quickly the pool" without using a preposition. So, there is no alternative construction that would make any more sense.

The only other way you could use the adverb is to comment on the *whole situation* by beginning the sentence with the adverb, and say "weirdly, I affected my friend", which means it was weird, perhaps 'surprising', that you had an effect on your friend.

Comment: @user38472 Thank you, glad it helped. I have made an edit to my answer, to clarify - you correctly used "affected" and "effect" in your sentence. I hope I've made the difference clear in my answer.

Comment: From the BBC: [*Adverbs of manner are **usually placed after the main verb***](https://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/flatmates/episode75/languagepoint.shtml#:~:text=Adverbs%20of%20manner%20%2D%20position,the%20adverb%20before%20the%20verb.). As in ***He swims fast***. And I'd say that *definitely* applies to OP's example today. But [apparently that wasn't the case](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=affected+him+strangely%2Cstrangely+affected+him&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=10) a couple of centuries ago.

Comment: @FumbleFingers usually, but not always. The example has more in common structurally with "I badly need a drink". Do you think the adverb "badly" should go after the verb "need"?

Comment: To be honest, ***weirdly*** sounds weird to me when modifying *most* verbs, apart from ***to be** [+ participle]* as in *He was weirdly dressed*. And in fact, I just checked NGrams for **He was weirdly** and **He weirdly**. As expected, the latter doesn't occur often enough to chart. Admittedly, **He badly** occurs somewhat less often than **He was badly** - but at least they're *comparable*, so I don't think ***badly*** and ***weirdly*** have much in common here.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Your example of "swims fast" is completely off the mark. "Fast", when used adverbially, is *irregular*. Use 'quickly' and it can be placed either side of the main verb. And what 'weirdly' sounds like to you is irrelevant, especially if you are arguing about adverb placement in general. As adverbs of manner (which usually end in '-ly'), the way they are used is comparable. Obviously, their meaning is different! I find your constant 'higher criticism' of my answers very strange. Perhaps I should take a backseat from answering and be more critical of others...

Comment: ***He swims fast*** wasn't my example. I just copied that text verbatim from the BBC website. Whatever - it's obvious you don't appreciate me commenting under your answers, so I'll try to remember not to do so in future.